# JavaScript to Convert Indented Text to HTML List Duplicating Top-Level <li>'s as <ul>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I am currently using the following script to convert indented plain text to HTML lists:

```
var bind, blank, convert, index, li, lineToMap, linesToMaps, parse, parseTuples, ptAccum, runConvert, tabCount, ul, ulEnd;

convert = function(text) {
  return parse(text.split('\n'));
};

li = function(t) {
  var html;
  html = "<li>" + t['line'] + "</li>";
  ptAccum.push(html);
  return html;
};

ul = function(t) {
  return ptAccum.push("<ul>" + (li(t)));
};

ulEnd = function() {
  return ptAccum.push("</ul>");
};

ptAccum = [];

index = 0;

parse = function(lines) {
  var ts;
  ts = linesToMaps(lines);
  ptAccum = ["<ul>"];
  index = 0;
  parseTuples(ts, 0);
  ulEnd();
  return ptAccum.join("\n");
};

parseTuples = function(tuples, level) {
  var stop, _p, _results;
  stop = false;
  _p = function() {
    var curLevel, t;
    t = tuples[index];
    curLevel = t['level'];
    index++;
    if (curLevel === level) {
      return li(t);
    } else if (curLevel < level) {
      index--;
      return stop = true;
    } else {
      ul(t);
      parseTuples(tuples, level + 1);
      return ulEnd();
    }
  };
  _results = [];
  while (!stop && index < tuples.length) {
    _results.push(_p());
  }
  return _results;
};

tabCount = function(line) {
  var c, count, i, inc, isTab, tc;
  tc = 0;
  c = '\t';
  count = 0;
  if (line) {
    count = line.length;
  }
  i = 0;
  isTab = function() {
    return c === '\t';
  };
  inc = function() {
    c = line.charAt(i);
    if (isTab()) {
      tc++;
    }
    return i++;
  };
  while (isTab() && i < count) {
    inc();
  }
  return tc;
};

lineToMap = function(line) {
  return {
    line: line,
    level: tabCount(line)
  };
};

blank = function(line) {
  return !line || line.length === 0 || line.match(/^ *$/);
};

linesToMaps = function(lines) {
  var line, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = lines.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    line = lines[_i];
    if (!(blank(line))) {
      _results.push(lineToMap(line));
    }
  }
  return _results;
};

runConvert = function() {
  var result;
  result = convert($('#textarea-plain-text').val());
  $('#textarea-converted-text').val(result);
  return $('#div-converted-text').html(result);
};

bind = function() {
  return $('#list-conversion-button').click(runConvert);
};

$(bind);
```

With two small exceptions, this script is doing exactly what it should.  Unfortunately, one of these exceptions makes the script virtually unusable for its intended purpose (making HTML lists out of indented directory trees).  The main issue is that the script seems to duplicate any top-level `li` as a `ul`.  Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/3ZuEK/5/) with a form using this script.  As you can see, it is clearly duplicating items when it should not be doing so.

The other small issue is that I would like to modify the script to append `<span class="folder"></span>` to any `li` item ending with a semicolon and append `<span class="file"></span>` to any `li` item not ending with a semicolon.  However, this is a much smaller issue than the duplication bug.

Answer (score 0):

While the specific question (i.e., why the script in the question itself is duplicating top-level `li`'s when creating new `ul`'s) asked in this thread remains unanswered, it may be helpful to others who find this thread to have a solution to the underlying problem (i.e., generating HTML lists from indented text).  Toward that end, here is a page which is currently using a working script to accomplish just that: http://w3c.docs.omnifora.com/tools/convert-plain-text-to-html-list/.  Naturally, the script can easily be pulled from the source of the page (the script itself is named "indented-text-to-html-with-glyphicons.js").